# About the proof of higher regularity boundary Harnack inequality

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, harmonic-functions

I’m reading a note on higher regularity boundary Harnack inequality by D. DE SILVA AND O. SAVIN and I’m kind of confused of the case k=1.

In the paper they used the Hopf lemma to show that $u_\nu>c>0$, but, as the boundary regularity is just $C^{1, \alpha}$, I don’t think that we can directly use Hopf lemma.

I tried to use the transformation of coordinates to do make a better regularity of boundary, but it only works in the divergence form of equations. I have no clue to the non-divergence form. Is there any way to do this estimate?

Comment: This is the paper, right? https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.2588.pdf

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte Yes it is the paper I’m reading. The other conditions doesn’t seem that essential. Could you please tell that where the claim $u_{\nu}$ is bounded? It seems that I’ve missed the condition.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte yes I do want to know how to get this condition. Did they claim it? I have no idea ever reading it… Could you please tell where they claimed it?

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte But, as the boundary is $C^{1, \alpha}$, we cannot get the interior ball condition. How to use Hopf lemma here?

Comment: In the proof of Hopf Lemma, the smoothness of the boundary is used when claiming that there is a small ball contained in $\Omega$ whose closure is tangent to the boundary at $x$ and intersects the boundary only at $x$. But isn't this what the authors assume at the fourth line of Section 2? (although they should also have added that they keep the assumption $x_n>g(x')$ made in the fourth line of the Introduction).

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte I don’t think so. You may read a paper of Junyan Zheng. Or, you can consider an example that $y=|x|^{1+\alpha}$, which fits the condition of g, but you can see that there is no interior ball at (0,0)

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Comment: @AlessandroDellaCorte Thank you anyway. It’s happy to discuss with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit:* The result is fine: Hopf's lemma was proved in

- G. Giraud, *Problèmes de valeurs à la frontière relatifs à certaines donn ás discontinues*, Bull. de la Soc. Math. de France, 61 (1933), 1–54

Below is my incorrect answer (which I keep for reference), where I mistakenly assumed that $C^{1,Dini}$ is stronger than $C^{1,\alpha}$.

---

*Old answer:*

Looks like you are right: the regularity assumption on the boundary is insufficient, although I did not check this very carefully.

You may have a look at the paper *A counterexample to the Hopf-Oleinik lemma (elliptic case)* by D. E. Apushkinskaya and A. I. Nazarov, [DOI:10.2140/apde.2016.9.439](https://doi.org/10.2140/apde.2016.9.439), [arXiv:1503.02179](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02179). Let me quote from p. 2 of this paper:

> The reduction of the assumptions on the boundary of $\Omega$ up to $C^{1,Dini}$-regularity was realized for various elliptic operators in the papers [Wid67], [Him70] and [Lie85] (see also [Saf08]). A weakened form of the Hopf-Oleinik lemma (the existence of a boundary point $x_1$ in any neighborhood of $x_0$ and a direction $\ell$ such that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \ell}(x_1) \ne 0$) was proved in [Nad83] for a much wider
> class of domains including all Lipschitz ones. We mention also the paper
> [Swe97] where the behavior of superharmonic functions near the boundary
> of 2-dimensional domains with corners is described in terms of the main
> eigenfunction of the Dirichlet Laplacian.
>
> The sharpness of some requirements was confirmed by corresponding
> counterexamples constructed in [Wid67], [Him70], [KH75], [Saf08], [ABM$^+$11] and [Naz12]. In particular, the counterexamples from [Wid67], [Him70] and
> [Saf08] show that the Hopf-Oleinik result fails for domains lying entirely in
> non-Dini paraboloids.

Later, the paper shows that lack of "Dini condition" on the boundary invalidates the assertion of Hopf's lemma.

Comment: Thank you for this reference. I think I would pay some time on it.

Comment: I’ve just read some of the references and maybe we can use thm. 1.8. in https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.0522v1.pdf to get the estimate? Holder estimate would allow us to get the interior Q-condition.

Comment: Ah, that's right! I'll edit the answer momentarily.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It’s happy to discuss with you